# Insert if data not exists using stored procedure with xml as input

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have xml which is passed as input to a stored procedure for a bulk insert. My xml as below,

```
NewDataSet>
- <Table1>
  <StationId>1</StationId> 
  <DateOfEvent>2013-11-15</DateOfEvent> 
  <Year>2013</Year> 
  <WeekOfYear>46</WeekOfYear> 
  <MonthOfYear>11</MonthOfYear> 
  <ItemType>CATEGORY</ItemType> 
  <ItemName>10234</ItemName> 
  <Clicks>1</Clicks> 
  <SiteName>sandvikas</SiteName> 
  </Table1>
```

I have written a stored procedure as below,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertQuestion]
    (

        @XmlQuestionMeasurements xml

    )
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @docHandle int

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XmlQuestionMeasurements

    --insert data in to EP_QuestionMeasurement table
    Insert into Analytics(StationId,DateOfEvent,Year,WeekOfYear,MonthOfYear,ItemType,ItemName,Clicks,SiteName)
    SELECT StationId,DateOfEvent,Year,WeekOfYear,MonthOfYear,ItemType,ItemName,Clicks,SiteName
    FROM Openxml( @docHandle, '/NewDataSet/Table1', 2) 
    WITH ( StationId int,DateOfEvent date,  Year int ,WeekOfYear int,MonthOfYear int, ItemType VARCHAR(50),ItemName VARCHAR(50),Clicks int,SiteName VARCHAR(50)  ) 

END
```

Its inserts well. Now my issue is how i modify the stored procedure to prevent insert if same set of xml is passed again, To check if same data exists then prevent insert.
Need to check condition that if this itemname exists in this date then no insert.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do a [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)--that would insert if the data is not already present and would update if it is.

If that doesn't suit you, you could also try inserting from the XML into a temp table, and then from the temp table into Analytics `where tempTable.ItemName NOT IN(SELECT ItemName FROM Analytics)`  (assuming I'm understanding you correctly that `ItemName` is going to be distinct for all Analytics)

Comment: Itemname is unique based on station id's.I have same itemname present in different station like if station id 1 has itemname 301 and stan2 also has 301. if this two stations hit server at same time.